# Default Path Setting in Netlify TOML file

Tags: node.js, angular, netlify

I have Angular-JS app with nodeJS backend. I want to deploy my site to Netlify which do not support nodeJS deployment on back-end. Thats why I am configuring "app.set" and "app.use" information in toml file but do not know how to do it.
Anyone can help please ?

**NodeJS Code**

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));

// Use the passport package in our application
app.use(passport.initialize());
require('./../frontend/config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/api/admin/banners/',bannersApi);
app.use('/api/vendor/cms/',cmsApi);
app.use('/api/ebay', eBayApi);

app.get('/admin', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('admin/index', { title: "Chirp"});
});
app.get('/admin/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('admin/index', { title: "Chirp"});
});
```

**netlify.toml**

```toml
[build]
  # This is the directory to change to before starting a build.
  base    = "frontend/"
  # NOTE: This is where we will look for package.json/.nvmrc/etc, not root.
  # This is the directory that you are publishing from (relative to root of     your repo)
  publish = "frontend/"
  # This will be your default build command
  # command = "gulp"

# A basic redirects rule
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.ejs"
  status = 200
  force = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you are trying to deploy a server application to netlify which only supports client apps. You could make use of their `functions` offering if you want backend functionality tied with your client app.

Comment: But main issue is when my request goes to back end which makes the page from the front end folder and responds with the html page.
How it will be handled in netlify ?

Comment: Netlify is for client side applications. The backend is Netlify not you. This is a CDN more or less and your backend code "servig the front end" cannot be executed.